# Selecting a file using java Runtime class for dynamic values

Tags: java

After searching a lot in stackoverflow, all I could find was selecting the files with only static values.

```
public void findFile(String name,File file1)throws IOException
{      
    File[] list = file1.listFiles();       
    if(list!=null)  
    {                          
    for(File file2 : list)
    {            
        if (file2.isDirectory())
        {
            findFile(name,file2);             
        }
        else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(file2.getName()))
        {                                                              
            String p1 = ""+file2.getParentFile();
            File f2 = new File(p1);
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("explorer.exe /select, getAbsolutePath()");                            
        }             
    }        
  }
}
```

When I run the above code, because of the last line the code, I get directed to the Document rather than the path I entered. I would love to get some help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getAbsolutePath()` cannot be executed within `.exec` method as you intend to do it. `exec` is executed in windows shell environment aka `cmd`, so Java methods won't be recognized there.

If you want to append a path to your command, try in this way:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("explorer.exe /select " +f2.getAbsolutePath());
```